# Deploy and Run different version war in tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, war

I have a webApp build with spring and `dispatcher servlet` has this `<url-mapping>/</url-mapping>`
Is it possible to deploy different versions war of same web application in a tomcat?
I need different context path for different versions.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using maven you can take advantage of [resource filtering](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html) and parametrize the url your web.xml, the you can define a "production" profile which will always replace the variable with "/myApp" and a "dev" profile which will replace it with "/myApp-${project.version}" (project.version is a maven variable).

Now depending on how you need to deploy them, the discussion can take a right or a left turn.